# JavaFX webview detects youtube video has finished playing?

Tags: javafx, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Can anyone help me on how to detects when a YouTube video has finished playing? I planned to play the next video on the list whenever it detects the current video has already done playing. The YouTube player have the change event that detect when the video is done but I can't find a solution to do it on JavaFX when it using Webview 2.0.

Thank you in advance!